# Matlab Use function with structure parameter to interpolate

Tags: matlab, structure, interpolation

In MATLAB, I want to interpolate on a set of data using a function with the parameter input as a structure.  However, I am receiving an error.

I have a structure:

```
fruit.apples = [3 4 2 3 4]
fruit.oranges = [1 0 0 0 0]
fruit.grapes = [2 3 2 2 1]
```

So I want to interpolate this fruit structure to `samples = 20`;`

Here is my code:

```
function [output] = fruitbasket (fruit, samples)
sampleLength = linspace(1, numel(data), samples + numel(data));
sampleLength = sampleLength';
output = interp1(data, sampleLength);
```

My desire output is to interpolate each array with 25 apples, 25 oranges, and 25 grapes in the fruitbasket structure.  The code works if the structure is replaced with a variable, but I need to use a structure so I can pass multiple inputs into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`structfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/structfun.html) to apply a function to each element of the struct array. In this case, it would look like this:

```matlab
fruit.apples = [3 4 2 3 4];
fruit.oranges = [1 0 0 0 0];
fruit.grapes = [2 3 2 2 1];
samples = 20;

interp_data = @(d)interp1(d, linspace(1, numel(d), samples + numel(d)));
output = structfun(interp_data, fruit, 'UniformOutput',false);
```

`structfun` requires a handle to a function that it calls on each of the fields of the input structure. We create an anonymous function to pass to it, where we fill in the other parameters. The `sampleLength` in the OP is computed within this anonymous function, in case the elements within the struct are all different sizes. Finally, we set `'UniformOutput'` to `false` to tell `structfun` to return a struct of the same size, rather than a normal array with one value per input field.